# Edit css style for specific file

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wanna know, if there is way to edit one specific .html file from .css file. (without other css files or *style* tags)

You can edit specific class like this:

```css
p.class1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

So is there a way to edit css just for specific `.html` file? Something like this?:

```css
p.file1.html {
  color: blue;   \\text is blue just in file1.html
}
```

Comment: you should have a separate css file with html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is (in HTML) to insert a class attribute in the `body` tag of that file and then use CSS rules with combined selectors which contain that class as a parent. Those will only apply in that one file.

Example :

```
<body class="page_1">
   [ ... contents of page ... ]
</body>
```

And the CSS

```
.page_1 p {
  color: blue;
}
```

Note: CMSs like Wordpress insert classes like this automatically, so in this case you would only have to inspect your HTML code to see which classes were inserted in the `body` tag and create according CSS rules using that class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to go to your file1.html and add the :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssFileNameHere.css">
```

and put all styles you want in cssFileNameHere.css file , they will be applied just to the file1.html